# Yii2 работа с БД и связанными таблицами

Tags: база-данных, yii2, activerecord, join

**Имеются три таблицы:**

---

- users(id,**address_id)**
- **address(id**,home,**street_id**)
- **streets(id**,name)

---

**Связи между ними такие:**

**users**.address_id->**address**.streets_id->**streets**.name

Как через ActiveRecord выбрать массив USERS со вложенными массивами ADDRESS и вложенными в ADDRESS массивами STREETS.
С ADDRESS всё понятно:

```
$user = Users::find()->
             joinWith('address')->
             asArray()->
             all();
```

но из массива USERS таким же образом не получается достучаться до STREETS.

Помогите плиз.

Вот код **USERS**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'address_id' => 'Address ID',
        ];
    }
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Address::className(), ['id' => 'address_id']);
    }
}
```

Код **ADDRESS**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
class Address extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'address';
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'home' => 'Home',
            'street_id' => 'Street ID',
        ];
    }
    public function getStreets()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Street::className(), ['id' => 'street_id']);
    }
}
```

Код **STREETS**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
class Streets extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'streets';
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитывая, что у вас все связи hasOne, то нужно для начала переименовать методы.
В **ADDRESS** поменяйте **getStreets** на **getStreet**. Далее давайте разберем все на примере. Возьмем определенного юзера(**id=1**) и выведем его адрес и улицу.

```
$user = Users::find()->where(['id' => 1])->with(['address'])->one();
$adress = $user->address; //Адрес юзера
$street = $adress->street['name']; //Улица, согласно адресу
```

Все это работает, но если Вам нужно, чтобы у юзера было несколько адресов, то напишите, я дополню ещё ответ.

Comment: А можно чуть поподробнее про relation в данном конкретном случае. Если не сложно. Спасибо.

Comment: Выложите код моделей users, adress, streets и я Вам все там объясню путем дополнения своего ответа

Comment: Извините, что так долго.

Comment: Попробуйте. Я проверил сам все. Если данная структура вас не устроит, напишите. Так как я думаю, что нельзя ограничивать юзера с одним адресом.